# Jquery .animate() bug in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I have a web page in which jquery's animate() function that works perfectly fine in IE and FF, However it works abnormally in Chrome
here is my COde

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

ul, ol, dl {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.clearFloat{
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
#navigation{
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    left:0px;
    position:relative;
}
#navigation .title-list{
    width:450px;
    position:relative;
    left:-350px;
    height:100px;
}

#navigation .title{
    width:90px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#f5f5f2;
    position:absolute;
    right:-90px;
    top:35px;
}

#navigation .image{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#e5e5e4;
}
#navigation .image_hover{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#e5e5e4;
    display:none;
}
#navigation .title-list:hover .image{
    display:none;
}
#navigation .title-list:hover .image_hover{
    display:block;
}


#navigation .sub-menu{
    width:350px;
    height:30px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#f5f5f2;
    margin-top:35px;
    position:relative;
}
#navigation .title-list .drop-sub{
    display:none;
}

#navigation .title-list:hover .drop-sub{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    width:225px;
    right:20px;
    background-color:#CC3;
    padding-top:70px;
}

#navigation .sub-list{
    width:205px;
    padding:10px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#e5e5e4;
}

#navigation a{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#navigation .expand').hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({'left':'0px'},'fast');
    }, function(e) {
        $(this).stop().animate({'left':'-350px'},'fast');
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="title-list expand"><div class="title">About</div><img src="images/navigation/about.png" class="image" /><img src="images/navigation/about_hover.png" class="image_hover" />
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <div class="drop-sub">
                <div class="sub-list"><a href="#">College</a></div>
                <div class="sub-list"><a href="#">History</a></div>
                <div class="sub-list"><a href="#">Principal's Message</a></div>
                <div class="sub-list"><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
                <div class="sub-list"><a href="#">Gallery</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li class="title-list expand"><div class="title">Academics</div><img src="images/navigation/academics.png" class="image" /><img src="images/navigation/academics_hover.png" class="image_hover" />
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <div class="drop-sub">
                <div class="sub-list"><a href="#">Subjects</a></div>
                <div class="sub-list"><a href="#">Structure</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </li>


    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

when i run this code in FF or IE and hover over the menu item the menu item animates towards right as expected

When i run this code in chrome and hover over one of the menu items the menu first goes towards left a little and then goes towards right to its expected position

Anybody has solutions?

EDIT:------------------

This was happening because zoom was set to 110% in chrome.
However anyone has solutions for what can be done to avoid this??

Comment: Next time create a jsfiddle please, that way we can help you faster :) [here is yours](http://jsfiddle.net/Gk45E/)

Comment: I don't see the menu going to the left in Google Chrome Version 27..

Comment: Just put this in a fiddle, work fine on my chrome at the moment... maybe someone else can try

http://jsfiddle.net/dtcy7/

Comment: Everything works fine for me in both FF and Chrome. Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/fQ28H/) for your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is because positioning in Chrome is set to auto, on page load.

If you set *left* in your jQuery first off all to what it should be when the page loads, you should be fine.